# Toggling Threads

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

Should i keep using threads like this or should i use multiprocessing? I'm trying to get the while loop to toggle with a button press.

Thread:

```
class workingthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while 1:
           chat = skype.CreateChatWith(name)
           chat.SendMessage(message)
           t.sleep(timeou)
```

Start the thread:

```
def this(self,event):
    t = workingthread()
    t.start()
```

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough of an explanation for anyone to help.

Comment: I'll edit my post and add more info.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little bit unclear. I'm trying to focus on the "I'm trying to get the while loop to toggle with a button press" part. To my understanding, you want to have thread activity all the time (by activity I think of not killing the thread), but you only want to occasionally have while-loop body executed. The simplest solution is to implement a boolean variable and extending `workingthread` like this:

```
class workingthread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.doit = True

    def run(self):
        while 1:
           if doit:
               # if the execution of both statements is desired
               chat = skype.CreateChatWith(name)
               chat.SendMessage(message)
           # sleep in both cases
           t.sleep(timeou)
```

Now you can use a button event (whatever UI toolkit you are using), bind a method to it, and can toggle the `doit`-variable of the `workingthread`. Depending on `doit`, the while loop body is executed or not.